# How to implement page counter for an existing ASP.NET web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications

I am finding a good way to implement Page Counter Statistic for internal web application (so maybe I can not use Google Analytics to help me).

I want to find out which page in my web application that user does not visit anymore. So I can investigate the reason why there is no hit to that page. If it has a bug or that page is not necessary anymore.

The easy way that comes to mind is to add every page with some line of codes to update the page page view. But there are so many page in my web, so this will take a lot of time.

So is there any other way to make a simple web page statistic with minimize line of codes.

For more information
- Every user have to log in before using this web.
- There is session to store user's ID.
- I use .NET 1.1 as an environment and plan to migrate to .NET 2.0+ in the future.
- Page stat is not show on web, I just want the hit count and then analyze it.

Comment: Why dont you simply use the IIS Log files?

Comment: Good option I forgot about it because I can not directly access server due to the policy. I'll try to contact server admin.

Answer (score 1):

Google Analytics is probably your best bet. Although your site is internal, Google Analytics will still work so long as you are able to hit their server from within your network. I've used it on intranet sites before without any issues.

Comment: I try Google Analytics. But it seems like my web server can't connect to internet.

Comment: Your web server doesn't need to connect to Google, just your browser. Try accessing this URL on one a browser on your network. http://www.google-analytics.com/. If you can access this, you should be able to use GA on your intranet site.

Answer (score 0):

You use ashx files and invoke it via markup (i.e. as a jquery invocation or as using an image tag) or you add an HTTP module. Both can be implemented without recompiling-- just adding one more .dll to the bin and editing the web.config. There is not enough space in this text box to give full justice to the steps necessary to write a http module or handler and a hit counter.